# In reactjs I am not able to pass variable through context api

Tags: reactjs, class, react-context

I am trying to pass variables from a file in react js that is context.js to navbar.js but react.js warning says ProductConsumer was defined but never used and it keeps giving me those variables as undefined when I console.log() them.
The variable that I am trying to pass is "isAuthToCreateGym".
here is my context.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
const ProductContext = React.createContext();

class ProductProvider extends Component {
  isAuthToCreateGym = () => {
      console.log("vaibhav");
      return true;
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <ProductContext.Provider
        value={{
          isAuthToCreateGym: this.isAuthToCreateGym
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children};
      </ProductContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

const ProductConsumer = ProductContext.Consumer;

export { ProductProvider, ProductConsumer};
```

and here is my navbar.js(part of it where I defined ProductConsumer

```
<ProductConsumer>
                     {value=>{
                         console.log("value :"+value);
                         return value;
                     }}
</ProductConsumer>
```

Comment: You aren't showing how you nest your `ProductProvider` and the component containing the ProductConsumer.

Comment: ProductProvider's part is whole file I have not nested it in anything

Comment: this.children.props... do you mean this.props.children?

Comment: Oh sorry for that yes

Comment: Makes me wonder though if your ProductConsumer is a child of your ProductProvider? If the above snippet is from your actual project, I would guess that it isn't :)

Comment: Nope, it is not

Comment: Then it won't work. Your consumer needs to be nested in your provider.

Comment: Thanks I got the problem, the problem was same as you said